# 30-day rolling/moving sum when current date is missing

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, window-functions, impala

I have a table (`view_of_referred_events`) which stores the number of visitors for a given page.

```
date        country_id  referral    product_id  visitors
2016-04-01  216         pl          113759      1
2016-04-03  216         pl          113759      1
2016-04-06  216         pl          113759      13
2016-04-07  216         pl          113759      10
```

I want to compute the 30-day rolling/moving sum for this product, even for those days which are missing. So the end result should be something like the following:

```
date        country_id  referral    product_id  cumulative_visitors
2016-04-01  216         pl          113759      1
2016-04-02  216         pl          113759      1
2016-04-03  216         pl          113759      2
2016-04-04  216         pl          113759      2
2016-04-05  216         pl          113759      2
2016-04-06  216         pl          113759      15
2016-04-07  216         pl          113759      25
```

Now, this is a simplistic representation, because I have tens of different `country_id`, `referral` and `product_id`. I can't pre-create a table with all possible combinations of {`date`, `country_id`, `referral` and `product_id`} because this would become untreatable considering the size of the table. I don't also want to have a row in the final table if that specific {`date`, `country_id`, `referral` and `product_id`} didn't exist before.

I was thinking if there was an easy way to tell Impala to use the value of the previous row (the previous day) if in `view_of_referred_events` there are no visitors for that day.

I wrote this query, where `list_of_dates` is a table with a list of days from April 1st to April 7th.

```
select
  t.`date`,
  t.country_id,
  t.referral,
  t.product_id,
  sum(visitors) over (partition by t.country_id, t.referral, t.product_id order by t.`date`
                     rows between 30 preceding and current row) as cumulative_sum_visitors
from (
  selec
    d.`date`, 
    re.country_id, 
    re.referral, 
    re.product_id,
    sum(visitors) as visitors
  from list_of_dates d
  left outer join view_of_referred_events re on d.`date` = re.`date`
    and re.referral = "pl"
    and re.product_id = "113759"
    and re.country_id = "216"
  group by d.`date`, re.country_id, re.referral, re.product_id
  ) t
order by t.`date` asc;
```

This returns something similar to what I want, but not exactly that.

```
date        country_id  referral    product_id  cumulative_visitors
2016-04-01  216         pl          113759      1
2016-04-02  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016-04-03  216         pl          113759      2
2016-04-04  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016-04-05  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016-04-06  216         pl          113759      15
2016-04-07  216         pl          113759      25
```

Comment: Please clarify:  Your text and title are about a cumulative sum.  The query suggests you want a 30-day rolling/moving sum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how goo the performance will be, but you can do this by aggregating the data twice and adding 30 days for the second aggregation and negating the count.

Something like this:

```
with t as (
      select d.`date`, re.country_id, re.referral, re.product_id,
             sum(visitors) as visitors
      from list_of_dates d left outer join
           view_of_referred_events re
           on d.`date` = re.`date` and
              re.referral = 'pl' and
              re.product_id = 113759 and
              re.country_id = 216
      group by d.`date`, re.country_id, re.referral, re.product_id
     )
select date, country_id, referral, product_id,
       sum(sum(visitors)) over (partition by country_id, referral, product_id order by date) as visitors
from ((select date, country_id, referral, product_id, visitors
       from t
      ) union all
      (select date_add(date, 30), country_id, referral, product_id, -visitors
       from t
      ) 
     ) tt
group by date, country_id, referral, product_id;
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `GROUP BY d.`date`, re.country_id, re.referral, re.product_id` when you define `t`. In addition to that, this query doesn't carry over the values on those days where there are no visitors. In those days in fact the value for `country_id`, `referral`, `product_id` and `visitors` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added another sub query to get the value from the last row in the partition. I am not sure what version of hive/impala you are using, `last_value(column_name, ignore null values true/false)` is the syntax.

I assume you are trying to find the cumulative counts over a 30 days (month), I recommend using month field to group the rows. The month could come either from your dimension table `list_of_dates` or just `substr(date, 1, 7)` and get the cumulative counts of visitors over `..rows unbounded preceding and current row`.

**query:**

```
select
  `date`,
  country_id,
  referral,
  product_id,
  sum(visitors) over (partition by country_id, referral, product_id order by `date`
                     rows between 30 preceding and current row) as cumulative_sum_visitors 
from (select
  t.`date`,
  -- get the last not null value from the partition window w for country_id, referral & product_id
  last_value(t.country_id, true) over w as country_id,
  last_value(t.referral, true) over w as  referral
  last_value(t.product_id, true) over w as product_id 
  if(visitors = null, 0, visitors) as visitors 
from (
  select
    d.`date`, 
    re.country_id, 
    re.referral, 
    re.product_id,
    sum(visitors) as visitors
  from list_of_dates d
  left outer join view_of_referred_events re on d.`date` = re.`date`
    and re.referral = "pl"
    and re.product_id = "113759"
    and re.country_id = "216"
  group by d.`date`, re.country_id, re.referral, re.product_id
  ) t
window w as (partition by t.country_id, t.referral, t.product_id order by t.`date`
                     rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)) t1
order by `date` asc;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the current version of Impala doesn't support the ignore `NULL` values in the `LAST_VALUE` function.